# How to replace a left parenthesis with sed?

Tags: sed

I have to replace `(` with some character in my file, and I can't do it. `\(` is used for grouping in sed and when I used `\\(` with sed, it treated it as `\(` character not as just `(`. It seems like a tricky case to me.

Comment: Suggestion: if you just want to substitute a character for another, use `tr`(anslate): `echo 'Hello (world)' | tr '()' '[]'`; it outputs `Hello [world]`.

Answer (score 77):

If you use sed *without* `-r` (extended regular expressions) it will work as it uses `\(\)` rather than `()` for grouping:

```
sed -e 's/(/X/g'
```

For example

```
$ echo "foo (bar) (baz)" | sed -e 's/(/X/g'
foo Xbar) Xbaz)
```

If you want to use `-r` you can put `(` inside `[]`, e.g.

```
sed -re 's/[(]/X/g'
```

As [Lekensteyn remarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64195/how-to-replace-parenthesis-with-sed/64197#comment91959_64195) using `tr` might be more appropriate as you are merely replacing and you do not need the full power of regular expressions.

Comment: TL;DR: Don't escape it.

Comment: I used this to replace php's deprecated "split" with "explode" function, making sure "split" is preceded by a space and followed by a "(". `grep -lRZ " split(" . | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/ split(/ explode(/g'`